# Sequelize Order not returning sorted results

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When I pass the sequelize ORM query to a nodejs server the results are returned unsorted. I'm expecting the ID column to be sorted by DESC.

```
// FETCH All Customers
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    Section.findAll({
        order: [["id", 'DESC']]
         }).then(sections => {
            // Send All Customers to Client
            res.json(sections.sort(function(c1, c2){return c1.id - c2.id}));
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({msg: "error", details: err});
        });
};
```

The results are returned in an ascending order instead of descending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the secondary sort function as order already does the sorting:

```
// FETCH All Customers
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    Section.findAll({
        order: [["id", 'DESC']]
         }).then(sections => {
            // Send All Customers to Client
            res.json(sections);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({msg: "error", details: err});
        });
};
```